# Finding model with query strings

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So looking at the ember docs page here: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-records/

Ember says the following:

```
this.store.find('person', { name: "Peter" }); // => GET to /persons?name='Peter'`
```

So with this logic I did something like this

```
return this.store.find('entry', {week: params.week_id});
```

But for some weird reason ember is not making a get request with something like this

```
/entries?week=12
```

instead it's not sending any requests and neither is it returning any errors.

What's wrong exactly?

Comment: Try logging the `this.store...` to console to see what you're getting before trying to return it. Not familiar with Ember, but could you be getting a deferred?

Comment: Please post the lines from your `App.Router.map()` call that relate to this route.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the difference between the definitions for `App.Person` and `App.Entry`.

- `Person` defines a `name` property; but does `Entry` define a `week` property?
- Check if you have a custom adapter for either of them. It looks like `Person` is using `DS.RESTAdapter`, but `Entry` might not be. Check that there is not a model-specific adapter for entry, e.g. `App.EntryAdapter = ...`

Comment: I don't believe you need to have the parameter as a property of the model you are querying.